# mysql DATE fieldtype to return value as years

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a birthdate column in my table, it is a DATE field type.

I want to run a query and return that column's results in years old.

So 2010-07-01 would return 4 (for 4 years)

Another example: 2002-01-20 would return 12 (for 12 years).

Is there a mysql function that does that?

Comment: Answered few days back on DOB calculation hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099562/calculate-age-with-decimals-from-date-of-birth/24099709#24099709

Comment: Try `select timestampdiff(YEAR,'2010-07-01',now());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several examples for exactly those cases on the **official manual** page (which I suggest to always refere to):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birth, CURDATE()) AS age
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date_field) / 365.25,2), ' years old')
```

Comment: It's not usual to give the age in years otherwise than in full years. Ok very minors state that they are three and a quarter years old :-)

Comment: try this if you would like them to never be 0...  if(FORMAT(DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date_field) / 365.25,2) < 1, 'almost 1 year old',CONCAT(FLOOR(FORMAT(DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date_field) / 365.25,2))), ' years old')

Comment: In old times (MySQL 4.x or older) it was a tedious procedure to get the difference in full years for every valid combination of dates. But since [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) exists, it's an easy one, see the answer of @DanFromGermany.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!